# Getting list of opcodes from PANDA trace

Tags: disassembly, x86, qemu

As answer to the post "Using QEmu monitor interface to extract execution traces from a binary?", one of the PANDA authors [outlined](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/4779/11830) how QUEMU may be used to record execution traces.

I would like to do it with PANDA.

I found that the QEMU function `cpu_memory_rw_debug(env, pc, buf, size, is_write);` allows to access the guest's memory. Yet, I don't know how much memory I have to read, because the size of the opcodes differ.

PANDA provides the function `panda_disas`:

> ```
> void panda_disas(FILE *out, void *code, unsigned long size);
> ```
>
> Writes a textual representation of disassembly of the guest code at
>   virtual address code of size bytes.

But same question here, how do I determine the size of the instruction?

As `PANDA_CB_INSN_EXEC` and `PANDA_CB_INSN_TRANSLATE` do not provide the size of the instruction, I figured it must be in `CPUState`.

I looked into `cpu.h` and `cpu-all.h` but couldn't find anything.

Is there another approach or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment PANDA doesn't provide information about the instruction size (which isn't known before translation) at the level of an individual instruction. One thing you *can* do, however, is get the size of an entire basic block once it has been translated by QEMU using `PANDA_CB_AFTER_BLOCK_TRANSLATE` and then look at the `tb->size` field. You can then cache the disassembly for that block and print it out in a `PANDA_CB_BEFORE_BLOCK_EXEC` callback.

Here is a plugin that uses this trick to compute rolling instruction opcode histograms using the [capstone disassembler](http://www.capstone-engine.org/). You'll have to adapt it a bit to get a full instruction trace, but it should demonstrate the principle.

```
// This needs to be defined before anything is included in order to get
// the PRIx64 macro
#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS

extern "C" {

#include "config.h"
#include "qemu-common.h"

#include "panda_plugin.h"
#include "panda/panda_common.h"
#include "rr_log.h"
#include <capstone/capstone.h>

}

#include <map>
#include <string>

typedef std::map<std::string,int> instr_hist;


// These need to be extern "C" so that the ABI is compatible with
// QEMU/PANDA, which is written in C
extern "C" {

bool init_plugin(void *);
void uninit_plugin(void *);

}

#define WINDOW_SIZE 100

csh handle;
cs_insn *insn;
bool init_capstone_done = false;
target_ulong asid;
int sample_rate = 100;
FILE *histlog;

// PC => Mnemonic histogram
std::map<target_ulong,instr_hist> code_hists;

// PC => number of instructions in the TB
std::map<target_ulong,int> tb_insns;

// Circular buffer PCs in the window
target_ulong window[WINDOW_SIZE] = {};

// Rolling histogram of PCs
instr_hist window_hist;
uint64_t window_insns = 0;
uint64_t bbcount = 0;

void init_capstone(CPUState *env) {
    cs_arch arch;
    cs_mode mode;
#ifdef TARGET_I386
    arch = CS_ARCH_X86;
    mode = env->hflags & HF_LMA_MASK ? CS_MODE_64 : CS_MODE_32;
#elif defined(TARGET_ARM)
    arch = CS_ARCH_ARM;
    mode = env->thumb ? CS_MODE_THUMB : CS_MODE_ARM;
#endif

    if (cs_open(arch, mode, &handle) != CS_ERR_OK) {
        printf("Error initializing capstone\n");
    }
    init_capstone_done = true;
}

void add_hist(instr_hist &a, instr_hist &b) {
    for (auto &kvp : b) a[kvp.first] += kvp.second;
}

void sub_hist(instr_hist &a, instr_hist &b) {
    for (auto &kvp : b) a[kvp.first] -= kvp.second;
}

void print_hist(instr_hist &ih, uint64_t window_insns) { 
    fprintf(histlog, "%" PRIu64 " ", rr_get_guest_instr_count());
    fprintf(histlog, "{");
    for (auto &kvp : ih) {
        fprintf (histlog, "\"%s\": %f, ", kvp.first.c_str(), kvp.second/(float)window_insns);
    }
    fprintf(histlog, "}\n");
}

// During retranslation we may end up with different
// instructions. Since we don't have TB generations we just
// remove it from the rolling histogram first.
void clear_hist(target_ulong pc) {
    for (int i = 0; i < WINDOW_SIZE; i++) {
        if (window[i] == pc) {
            window[i] = 0;
            window_insns -= tb_insns[pc];
            sub_hist(window_hist, code_hists[pc]);
        }
    }
}

static int after_block_translate(CPUState *env, TranslationBlock *tb) {
    size_t count;
    uint8_t mem[1024] = {};

    if (asid && panda_current_asid(env) != asid) return 0;

    if (!init_capstone_done) init_capstone(env);

    if (code_hists.find(tb->pc) != code_hists.end()) {
        clear_hist(tb->pc);
        return 0;
    }

    panda_virtual_memory_rw(env, tb->pc, mem, tb->size, false);
    count = cs_disasm_ex(handle, mem, tb->size, tb->pc, 0, &insn);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < count; i++)
        code_hists[tb->pc][insn[i].mnemonic]++;
    tb_insns[tb->pc] = count;
    return 1;
}

static int before_block_exec(CPUState *env, TranslationBlock *tb) {
    if (asid && panda_current_asid(env) != asid) return 0;

    if (window[bbcount % WINDOW_SIZE] != 0) {
        target_ulong old_pc = window[bbcount % WINDOW_SIZE];
        window_insns -= tb_insns[old_pc];
        sub_hist(window_hist, code_hists[old_pc]);
    }

    window[bbcount % WINDOW_SIZE] = tb->pc;
    window_insns += tb_insns[tb->pc];
    add_hist(window_hist, code_hists[tb->pc]);

    bbcount++;

    if (bbcount % sample_rate == 0) {
        // write out to the histlog
        print_hist(window_hist, window_insns);
    }
    return 1;
}

bool init_plugin(void *self) {
    panda_cb pcb;

    panda_arg_list *args = panda_get_args("insthist");
    const char *name = panda_parse_string(args, "name", "insthist");
    asid = panda_parse_ulong(args, "asid", 0);
    sample_rate = panda_parse_uint32(args, "sample_rate", 1000);

    char fname[260];
    sprintf(fname, "%s_insthist.txt", name);
    histlog = fopen(fname, "w");

    pcb.after_block_translate = after_block_translate;
    panda_register_callback(self, PANDA_CB_AFTER_BLOCK_TRANSLATE, pcb);
    pcb.before_block_exec = before_block_exec;
    panda_register_callback(self, PANDA_CB_BEFORE_BLOCK_EXEC, pcb);

    return true;
}

void uninit_plugin(void *self) {
    print_hist(window_hist, window_insns);
    fclose(histlog);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! My last idea was also to use capstone. But this way: 1.) Get 15 bytes (max. i386 opcode length) starting from PC, 2.) letting capstone disassemble the entire 15 bytes, 3.) taking the first struct (from the array of structs returned) and 4.) using the `.size` information from this struct. See http://www.capstone-engine.org/lang_c.html . What do you think? Could also try to make a plugin out of it so that others can re-use the code ... Yet, your solution probably has a better performance, as you avoid disassembling the same instructions twice or even more...

Comment: Your strategy should work for the most part. The one edge case is if you try to read 15 bytes near a page boundary where the next page is unmapped. The real instruction may not cross the page boundary, but trying to read 15 bytes will fail.

I think the real solution would be to add an `AFTER_INSN_TRANSATE` callback to PANDA that provides the size of the instruction in bytes (since QEMU's translator will have that information at that point).

Comment: Capstone is rather heavy-weight. If you only need to find instruction lengths, you might want to use a more light-weight solution such as https://github.com/greenbender/lend.

Comment: @BrendanDolan-Gavitt I like your suggestion to add an `AFTER_INSN_TRANSATE` callback to PANDA. However, I was not able to find the right spot where qemu has the info. Is it in `target-i386/translate.c`? Could you point me to the right location?

Comment: @BrendanDolan-Gavitt my guess: the size can be obtained at the end of function `disas_insn(DisasContext *s, target_ulong pc_start)` in `target-i386/translate.c`. disas_insn returns `s->pc` (which was incremented byte by byte when the opcode is parsed). This means `size = s->pc - pc_start`

Please tell me if I am wrong here.